# Fisher's Exact: why no test statistic for 2x2 tables in SPSS

Tags: spss, fishers-exact-test

Whenever I have used the Fisher's Exact test on tables larger than 2x2 contingency tables, SPSS has produced a test statistic that I can quote in my work. However, when I do the same with 2x2 tables, no test statistic is produced.

I want the way in which I report my results to appear standard throughout my thesis. Therefore do I (a) omit the test statistic that is provided for the larger tables or (b) find some way of calculating the test statistic?

A similar issue was noted in a question entitled "Fisher's Exact test value" but the answers didn't address this issue specifically.

Comment: Why SPSS doesn't (appear to) do this I can't address and is any case arguably off-topic here, but find some other software is indeed one short answer (and not intended to be dismissive). I have not checked, but I would be amazed if R did not offer this. Stata certainly can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fisher's Exact Test value in SPSS](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81482/fishers-exact-test-value-in-spss)

Comment: And another relevant question http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56773/3277

Comment: @ttphns I don't think so; neither of those addresses the OP's question about getting a test for 2x2 in SPSS.